# TFTP client based on java NIO

Tags: java, nio, tftp

I am trying to implement TFTP client using Java NIO. But it leads to error:

> network error: Address already in use: bind

Code snippet is shared here.

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress("10.86.4.250",69);
channel.socket().bind(isa);
channel.configureBlocking(false);
```

As I am new to this networking concept, I couldn't understand the cause. Any help in resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing a client, you should `.connect()` to a socket, rather than `bind()`'ing (that's for the server), eg.:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( "10.86.4.250" , 69 ) );
...
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how [TFTPClient](https://java.net/projects/slamd/sources/svn/content/trunk/slamd/src/com/sun/slamd/tftp/TFTPClient.java) client from implemented.
Methods `initialiseSocket` and `sendTftpPacket` are more interesting.

Basically you do not need to bind the socket().